# clearInterval Not being set

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to create a button that will toggle setInterval/clearInterval. The setInterval will function correctly, but when the button is clicked again, clearInterval is not done. Is this a variable scope issue or a problem with how the functions are setup?

http://jsfiddle.net/BxLps/1/

```
$(function () {
    var int;
    var onrepeat;

    $('button[id^=temp]').click(function () {
        window.id = $(this).attr("value");
        var int = setInterval(doAjax, 3000);

        if (onrepeat == false) {
            $(this).find('i').addClass("fa-spin");
            doAjax();
            int;
            onrepeat = true;
        } else {
            clearInterval(int);
            $(this).find('i').addClass("fa-spin");
            onrepeat = false;
        }
    });
});
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: "a=cur-temp&id=" + id,
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#cur-temp").html(msg);
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: what is the `int;` for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue is it's creating new intervals each time. Think about it, every "click" is running that code (so it's doing a setInterval).

Solution is to declare int once (and only once) outside the click. Then move the setInterval inside the condition

```
var int;
var onrepeat;

$('button[id^=temp]').click(function () {
    window.id = $(this).attr("value");

    if (onrepeat == false) {
        $(this).find('i').addClass("fa-spin");
        doAjax();
        int = setInterval(doAjax, 3000);
        onrepeat = true;
    } else {
        clearInterval(int);
        $(this).find('i').addClass("fa-spin");
        onrepeat = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a variable scope issue?

Yes. You've used [`var int`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) twice, with the second one introducing a local variable where you did want to access to outer one.

However, you still might get problems with having a single `int` variable for all the elements with that selector. I have now created an object which stores the interval ids per id of the element on an object, you might as well use an `each` loop to create an extra variable per element.

Also, your global variable `id` is horrible, better use a parameter for the `doAjax` function.

```
$(function () {
    var ints = {};

    $('button[id^=temp]').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("value");

        if (id in ints) {
            $(this).find('i').removeClass("fa-spin");
            clearInterval(ints[id]);
            delete ints[id];
        } else {
            $(this).find('i').addClass("fa-spin");
            doAjax(id);
            ints[id] = setInterval(function() {
                doAjax(id);
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: He gave the button an id so I assume he intends there to be only one. Not sure if the list of ids is necessary...

Comment: @isick: The selector looks as if there were multiple buttons whose ids began with `temp`. I haven't looked at the fiddle, though. If he really wants only a single button, a simple `int` variable will be fine but then `$('#temp').click()` should be useed

Comment: I totally glazed over the caret. You could very well be right!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the second declaration of `int`.

```
$(function () {

    var int;
    $('button[id^=temp]').click(function () {
        window.id = $(this).attr("value");
        int = setInterval(doAjax, 3000); //remove var to prevent new declaration

        if (onrepeat == false) {
            $(this).find('i').addClass("fa-spin");
            doAjax();
            int;
            onrepeat = true;
        } else {
            clearInterval(int);
            $(this).find('i').addClass("fa-spin");
            onrepeat = false;
        }
    });
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9tkU2/

Comment: No need to assign `int` an initial value in the declaration, particularly not one of a different type that is even appropriate.

Comment: No need to make it global!

Comment: Bigger issue is the setInterval is declared every click (clicks on and clicks off) so that's why it appears it's not toggling off when it's really toggling off and on again (and multiplying too). See my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

> Your problem is the scope of your variable `int`. You are declaring it inside the function and by the time you think are clearing the interval the original variable `int` has been destroyed.
>
> so just remove the var from the `var int =...` you have inside the function

if the problem persists continue to read below.

Ok, I have suffered this same problem too many time and usually I just let it be,
But most times I realize that after clearing interval the interval continues to run, and this might affect the performance of the device (it's like having an infinite loop).

So I did a little bit of research and I found out what the problem was and I wrote a simple code to solve it.

Now when you start an interval (most likely triggered by an event) in most cases, more than one instance of that interval is declared (for whatever reason)...

So when you clear the interval later, you only clear the *top-level interval, and the next level interval sets in.
(top-level might not be the correct word)

So to truly clear the interval I used the method below:

**Setting the interval:**

```
if(!timer)   
    timer =setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
```

**Clearing the interval:**

```
clearInterval(timer);
timer=null;
while (timer!== null){
    timer=null;
}
```

you might decide to clear the interval inside the while loop, but I found that this works for me and it's quite efficient than that.

> Make sure you check the scope of the interval variable (i.e timer in the case above)